# Get center of uiimageview in array

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a bunch of uiimageview's in a NSMutableArray, and the UIImageviews are animating about the view. But I can't figure out how to get the current location of any of the image views

```
for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++){
UIImageView *temp = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"POSITION:%@",temp.center.x);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move an UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862084/move-an-uiimage)

Comment: Dude that's not even close to what I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you should not be able to get that number. But `temp.center.x` is a `CGFloat`, and you have to use `%f` instead of `%@` if you want to print it. That might be your problem?

Comment: it returns null, also if I try a comparison using that float (i.e. if that position is in a range) it still doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you have valid UIImageViews in your array?

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++){
UIImageView *temp = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
}
```

You should see something like this in the log:

```
<UIImageView: 0x...>
```